# How to start jquery datepicker with focus

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and would like to start datepicker with focus.

My first textbox is a date field and I have tried to give the box focus with javascript but datepicker won't come up unless I click somewhere else on the page and then give it focus by clicking inside the box.

Is there a way to start datepicker with focus and maybe have the widget start immediately when the page loads then drop focus when the user leaves the box?

```
  $( "#date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy"
  });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this - http://www.jsfiddle.net/wnUWQ/embedded/result

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepick").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy"
    });
    $("#datepick").focus(function() {
        $("#datepick").datepicker("show");
    });
    $("#datepick").focus();
});
```

EDIT: 
The [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function of $(document) object is fired when the DOM is completely loaded in the browser. First we attach the `datepicker` to the `input`, and then we attach a [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) eventhandler that shows the datepicker and last we set the focus on to the input.

This could all be [chained](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/jQuery-Understanding-the-chain) into one line as in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepick").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy"
    }).focus(function() {
        $("#datepick").datepicker("show");
    }).focus();
});
```

Comment: Probably to give people time to elaborate the answer - as I have done now... ;-)

Comment: +1 @Floyd for a thorough answer and @jim, it could be to allow some answers to *stack* .. It is Stack Overflow after all ;)