# AUI datepicker: pop up datepicker on focus of element

Tags: liferay, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

How can i make AUI-datepicker to pop up on the focus of element. cuurrently it only pop up on click of element.

Here is code

Script:

```
 YUI().use('aui-datepicker',
  function(Y) {
    new Y.DatePicker(
      {
        trigger: '.date-selector',
        popover: {
          zIndex: 1
        },
      }
    );
  }
);
```

and Tag

```
<aui:input id="startDate" name="startDate" cssClass="date-selector" label="startDate">
```

and one more thing how can i range date?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886239/how-to-start-jquery-datepicker-with-focus

Comment: @ParkashKumar i know how to implement in jquery. but i need it in aui bcoz i have used aui tags and script in my portlet. so it would better to go with aui-datepicker.

Comment: http://blogs.xtivia.com/home/-/blogs/liferay-alloy-ui-calendar-datepicker-and-datepickerselect may be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Datepicker popup is handled by [DatePickerPopover](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.DatePickerPopover.html) class of aui-datepicker module. There is [show()](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.DatePickerPopover.html#method_show) method in datepicker class to open popup.

```
<input id="startDate" name="startDate" class="date-selector" onfocus="openDatePicker();">
<script>
    var datePicker;
    YUI().use('aui-base','aui-datepicker', function(Y) {
        datePicker = new Y.DatePicker({
            trigger: '#startDate',
            popover: {
                zIndex: 10,
            },
            calendar: {
                maximumDate: new Date()
            }
        });
    });
    function openDatePicker() {
        datePicker.getPopover().show();
    }
</script>
```

Date can be ranged by adding maximumDate and minimumDate attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this something like this**:

```
<aui:input name="taskStartDate" autocomplete="off" cssClass='font-size' id="taskStartDate"  onFocus="onClickOfStartDate();" required="true" inlineLabel="true" label=" "/>    

<aui:script>
    function  setactualStartDate(){

        AUI().use('aui-datepicker', function(A) {
            var simpleDatepicker1 = new A.DatePicker({
                trigger: '#<portlet:namespace />taskActualStartDate', 
                mask: '%Y-%m-%d',
                calendar: {
                    dateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
                },
            }).render('#<portlet:namespace />taskactualStartDatePicker');
        });
    }

    function onClickOfStartDate(){
        setStartDate();
    }
</aui:script>
```

Comment: it's not working for me. can u tell me taskActualStartDate and taskactualStartDatePicker are ID of which element